# Pseudorecord best practice when trigger fires but value should never change

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax, triggers

Consider the following tables and trigger, is there a need to specify :new.employee_id in the insert statement or is this generally considered best practice. The trigger will only fire on the salary column of the table and the employee_id should not be affected. Is the :new.employee_id syntax just good practice when creating triggers or unnecessary? Could there be a potential issue if this is not added?

Link to Oracle HR SCHEMA employees table
[Employees Table HR Schema](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/HR-sample-schema-table-descriptions.html#GUID-D3AB4410-FEA7-49A4-A0E4-9E75B2ED40DA)

```
CREATE TABLE salary_log (
    whodidit VARCHAR2(25), whendidit timestamp,
    oldsalary NUMBER,
    newsalary NUMBER,
    emp_affected NUMBER);
    
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER saltrig
        AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF salary ON employees
        FOR EACH ROW 
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO salary_log
        VALUES(user,sysdate, :old.salary, :new.salary, :new.employee_id);
        END;
```

Comment: Yes, if you do not include it then your log will have NULL in `emp_affected`. You will not know what employee's salary was updated or inserted. It is not only good practice it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: As an after thought, since `whendidit` column is defined a a timestamp you probably want CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of SYSDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to NOT include it:

1. You would have to alter your trigger code to explicitly name the columns you are supplying values for, and
2. Your log table would show that *someone's* salary changed, who did it and what the old and new values are, but you would not know *whose* salary was changed.  The data in that column would be null.

> Is the :new.employee_id syntax just good practice when creating triggers or unnecessary?

If you want this value in your log table, then it is required.

Comment: Now if the employee_id column on the salary_log table had a not null constraint would you still be able to commit the original change on the employees table and error on the trigger? I'm not sure where to expect the error to come from

Comment: @z3ke In your example, if you have a not null constraint on the emp_affected column and you don't provide a value for it in the trigger, it will throw an ORA-01400 (cannot insert NULL) error at the time of inserting or updating the row and your original insert or update to employees will be rolled back.